# Am I using the semicolon correctly here or should a period be more appropriate?

Tags: semicolons

In this sentence, can I use a semicolon, or is a period more appropriate?

> When she was a child, she wanted to be an explorer; now she can't even leave her own house.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are the two clauses grammatically complete sentences?

Are they closely linked to each other?

The answer to the first question is yes. The second question is a matter of judgement. But there is a clear connection between the sentences, so a semicolon would be a good choice.